# fastest way to invoke a process from python?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

What is the fastest/most efficient method to execute an executable from python?  It seems to me that os.system is faster than subprocess.popen.   I would like to be able to read the lines that come out of this other process, but far more important than anything else is speed.

Comment: Why is speed important? If speed is so critical, why are you trying to accomplish things (a) by starting other processes; (b) with Python? What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: I second what Karl said, and: `It seems to me that os.system is faster than subprocess.popen`. Are you *really* sure? And does it matter?

Comment: Unless you require threading etc., the difference in performance is negligible. You should be optimizing the Python code itself, and the calls to the processes (e.g. what options you use, etc.)

Comment: When you measured, what measurements did you produce?  Could you please share them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect any speed difference between, say, `os.system` and `os.execv` and `subprocess.Popen`, to be swamped by the expense of starting a new process (and the context-switching needed to actually run it). Therefore I recommend using `subprocess` first and measuring the performance.

One possible performance consideration: `os.system` and `subprocess.Popen(shell=True, ...)` cause an extra shell process to be created. In most cases, that shell isn't necessary. It's wasteful to create it; you get twice as many processes as you need for no benefit.