# What is the fastest way to execute commands in python?

Tags: python, performance, execute

I'm writing a Python script and I need to call some commands, for example creating directories, deleting files, execute docker commands, git commands, `make` command etc.

What is the fastest way to invoke such commands?

Should I use `os.system` or `subprocess`?

The Python script will run on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Related: [Speed difference betwen subprocess.call() and os.system()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69117088/2745495), and [fastest way to invoke a process from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502469/2745495)

Comment: @GinoMempin Windows and Linux. Just added it! Thanks